# Calling other request mapping from rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to call other rest controller from reqest mapping .

```
@RestController
class MyController{
   @Autowired
   OtherController other
   @RequestMapping(/{token}/add)
   public MyDto add(String token){
      String[] tokens = token.split("\\.");
          I want to call process input from method from Other controller and send token[1] item as path param
   }

}

@RestController
public class OtherController{

   @RequestMapping(/token/process)
   public processInput(@PathVariable token)
   {

   }

}
```

How to send spited token to other param as path param. Could you please advice the calling strategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to call another controller. You can simply inject your `Controller` into the class you would like to make that call in. This allows you to use the `OtherController` controller as if it was a Service component.

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    private final OtherController otherController;

    public MyController(@Autowired OtherController otherController) {
        this.otherController = otherController;
    }

    @RequestMapping(/{token}/add)
    public MyDto add(String token){
      InputDto input=new InputDto();
      otherController.processInput(input);
   }
}
```

Comment: Other controller has path param how to send data via it

Comment: You would simply pass it as a variable into that controller.